# Concurrent Haskell Actions with Timeout

Tags: haskell, timeout, action, concurrency

how could one implement a function in concurrent haskell that either returns 'a' successfully or due to timeout 'b'?

```
timed :: Int → IO a → b → IO (Either a b)
timed max act def = do
```

Best Regards,
Cetin Sert

Note: the signature of timed can be completely or slightly different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implementing your desired `timed` on top of `System.Timeout.timeout` is easy:

```
import System.Timeout (timeout)

timed :: Int -> IO a -> b -> IO (Either b a)
timed us act def = liftM (maybe (Left def) Right) (timeout us act)
```

By the way, the common implementation of `timeout` is closer to this: (`$!` = `seq` to try to force evaluation of the returned value in the thread rather than only returning a thunk):

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay, killThread)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar (newEmptyMVar, putMVar, takeMVar)
import System.IO (hPrint, stderr)

timeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
timeout us act = do
    mvar <- newEmptyMVar
    tid1 <- forkIO $ (putMVar mvar . Just $!) =<< act
    tid2 <- forkIO $ threadDelay us >> putMVar mvar Nothing
    res <- takeMVar mvar
    killThread (maybe tid1 (const tid2) res) `catch` hPrint stderr
    return res
```

The implementation of `System.Timeout.timeout` in the libraries is a little more complex, handling more exceptional cases.

```
import Control.Concurrent  (forkIO, threadDelay, myThreadId, killThread)
import Control.Exception   (Exception, handleJust, throwTo, bracket)
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Unique         (Unique, newUnique)

data Timeout = Timeout Unique deriving Eq
timeoutTc :: TyCon
timeoutTc = mkTyCon "Timeout"
instance Typeable Timeout where { typeOf _ = mkTyConApp timeoutTc [] }
instance Show Timeout where
    show _ = "<<timeout>>"
instance Exception Timeout

timeout n f
    | n <  0    = fmap Just f
    | n == 0    = return Nothing
    | otherwise = do
        pid <- myThreadId
        ex  <- fmap Timeout newUnique
        handleJust (\e -> if e == ex then Just () else Nothing)
                   (\_ -> return Nothing)
                   (bracket (forkIO (threadDelay n >> throwTo pid ex))
                            (killThread)
                            (\_ -> fmap Just f))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first answer I could come up with. I needed this for a port scanner. o_O Forgot the admin password of my router and wanted to check which ports I had opened on our home server before that I could now repurpose and reuse ^ _ ^" ... This implementation should do the job for the time being.

```
module Control.Concurrent.Timed (timed) where

import Prelude hiding (take)
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import System.Process
import System.Timeout
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Environment

timed :: Int → IO a → b → IO (Either b a)
timed max act def = do

  w ← new
  r ← new

  t ← forkIO $ do
    a ← act
    r ≔ Right a
    e ← em w
    case e of
      False → kill =<< take w
      True  → return ()

  s ← forkIO $ do
    (w ≔) =<< mine
    wait max
    e ← em r
    case e of
      True  → do
        kill t
        r ≔ Left def
      False → return ()

  take r

timed_ :: Int → IO a → a → IO a
timed_ max act def = do
  r ← timed max act def
  return $ case r of
    Right a → a
    Left  a → a

(≔) = putMVar
new = newEmptyMVar
wait = threadDelay
em = isEmptyMVar
kill = killThread
mine = myThreadId
take = takeMVar
```

or just use [System.Timeout.timeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Timeout.html#v:timeout) -__-"